# Cmake module that improves upon CheckLibrariesExists

Tags: cmake

The following module `AssertLibraryFunction` improves upon `CheckLibrariesExists` in two respects:

- It honors the optional argument `REQUIRED` of `find_package`: if the check fails, it raises a `FATAL_ERROR`. It also honors `QUIET`.
- Its result is cached in a variable named `${LIBNAME}_${FUNCTION}`. Therefore, argument 4 of `CheckLibrariesExists`, `VARIABLE`, is no longer needed.

Of course this comes at a slight expense in flexibility. Nevertheless, I believe this module could help substantially in writing compact `Find<Package>.cmake` modules.

Questions:

- Is this novel functionality, or could I achieve about the same, with comparable brevity, with an existing module?
- Would it make sense to propose `AssertLibraryFunction` for inclusion in future cmake versions?
- Regardless of the above, are there ways to improve my cmake coding style?

Here the module `AssertLibraryFunction`:

```
#.rst:
# AssertLibraryFunction
# ---------------------
#
# ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION checks whether given libraries contain
# a given function. If this is not the case, a fatal error is raised.
#
# CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS (LIBNAME FUNCTION LOCATION)
#
# ::
#
#   LIBNAME  - library name (case sensitive)
#   FUNCTION - name of the function to be searched in ${LIBNAME}_LIBRARIES
#   LOCATION - where the library should be found (if unsure, use "")
#
#
# The following variables may be set before calling this macro to modify
# the way the check is run:
#
# ::
#
#   CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS = string of compile command line flags
#   CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS = list of macros to define (-DFOO=bar)
#   CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES = list of libraries to link
#   CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET = execute quietly without messages
#
# This function is meant to be used in Find<Package>.cmake modules,
# which in turn should be called through
#
# ::
#
#   find_package(<Package> [QUIET] [REQUIRED])
#
# Within a Find<Package>.cmake module, find_package_handle_standard_args
# must be called before any call of ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION.
# Typically, Find<Package>.cmake looks like the following:
#
# ::
# 
#   find_path(<Package>_INCLUDE_DIR <include_file>)
#   find_library(<Package>_LIBRARIES NAMES <library_name> <Package>)
#   
#   include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
#   find_package_handle_standard_args(<Package> DEFAULT_MSG <Package>_LIBRARIES <Package>_INCLUDE_DIR)
#   
#   include(AssertLibraryFunction)
#   assert_library_function(<Package> <function_name> "")
#   
#   mark_as_advanced(<Package>_INCLUDE_DIR <Package>_LIBRARIES)
#   
# The result of ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION is cached in a variable named
# ${LIBNAME}_${FUNCTION}.

#=============================================================================
# Based on CheckLibrariesExists (Copyright 2002-2009 Kitware, Inc.)
# Author: Joachim Wuttke (Copyright 2015 Forschungszentrum Jülich)
# License: BSD (see cmake License for details)
#=============================================================================


macro(alf_status_message _msg)
    if( ${LIBNAME}_FIND_QUIETLY )
    else()
        message(STATUS ${_msg})
    endif()
endmacro()

function(ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION LIBNAME FUNCTION LOCATION)
    set(LIBRARY ${${LIBNAME}_LIBRARIES})
    set(VARIABLE ${LIBNAME}_${FUNCTION})
    set(_MSG "Search ${FUNCTION} in ${LIBRARY}")
    if(DEFINED "${VARIABLE}")
        if(${${VARIABLE}})
            alf_status_message("${_MSG} -- cached")
            return()
        endif()
    endif()
    alf_status_message("Search ${FUNCTION} in ${LIBRARY}")
    set(MACRO_CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_DEFINITION
        "-DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=${FUNCTION} ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS}")
    set(CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY})
    if(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES)
        set(CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_LIBRARIES
            ${CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES})
    endif()
    try_compile(COMPILE_OK
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS}
        LINK_LIBRARIES ${CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_LIBRARIES}
        CMAKE_FLAGS
        -DCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS:STRING=${MACRO_CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS_DEFINITION}
        -DLINK_DIRECTORIES:STRING=${LOCATION}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT)

    if(${COMPILE_OK})
        if(NOT CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET)
            alf_status_message("${_MSG} -- found")
        endif()
        set(${VARIABLE} 1 CACHE INTERNAL "Library ${LIBRARY} has ${function}")
        file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeOutput.log
            "Determining if the function ${FUNCTION} exists in the ${LIBRARY} "
            "passed with the following output:\n"
            "${OUTPUT}\n\n")
    else()
        set(${VARIABLE} "" CACHE INTERNAL "Library ${LIBRARY} has no ${function}")
        file(APPEND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/CMakeError.log
            "Determining if the function ${FUNCTION} exists in the ${LIBRARY} "
            "failed with the following output:\n"
            "${OUTPUT}\n\n")
        if( ${LIBNAME}_FIND_REQUIRED )
            message(FATAL_ERROR "${_MSG} -- not found")
        else()
            alf_status_message("${_MSG} -- not found")
        endif()
    endif()
endfunction()
```

And here is a sample module `FindReadline.cmake` that would use the above:

```
# Find libreadline
#
# Usage:
#   find_package(Readline [REQUIRED] [QUIET])
#
# Sets the following variables:
#   - Readline_FOUND        .. true if library is found
#   - Readline_LIBRARIES    .. full path to library
#   - Readline_INCLUDE_DIR  .. full path to include directory
#
# Copyright 2015 Joachim Wuttke, Forschungszentrum Jülich.
# Redistribution permitted.

find_path(Readline_INCLUDE_DIR readline/readline.h)
find_library(Readline_LIBRARIES NAMES readline Readline)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs) # handles QUIET, REQUIRED; sets Readline_FOUND
find_package_handle_standard_args(Readline DEFAULT_MSG Readline_LIBRARIES Readline_INCLUDE_DIR)

include(AssertLibraryFunction)
assert_library_function(Readline rl_initialize "")
assert_library_function(Readline add_history "")

mark_as_advanced(Readline_INCLUDE_DIR Readline_LIBRARIES)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your changes would definetly improve [CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS()](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake).

If I understand correctly you want to improve upon something like

```
cmake_push_check_state()
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET ${Readline_FIND_QUIETLY})
check_library_exists("${Readline_LIBRARIES}" rl_initialize "" Readline_rl_initialize)
cmake_pop_check_state()
```

with

```
assert_library_function(Readline rl_initialize "")
```

#### assert_library_function() Review

After giving your code some test runs, here are my thoughts:

1. If I think about the `LIBNAME` parameter more in terms of a `PACKAGENAME` parameter, then you can make use of [`CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME.html):

   ```
   macro(alf_status_message _msg)
       if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME OR 
          NOT "${${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}_FIND_QUIETLY}")
           message(STATUS ${_msg})
       endif()
   endmacro()
   ```

   - The fact that `CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME` is defined inside a [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_package.html) call gives two new possibilities

     - omitting the `LIBNAME` parameter of `ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION()` completely
     - or extending `CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS()` itself with this kind of checks
2. With one of my first tries the find module was delivering `${${LIBNAME}_LIBRARIES}` as `Readline_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND`. So your function should probably check and exit if the library was not found with e.g.

   ```
   if (NOT LIBRARY)
       return()
   endif()
   ```
3. With your approach to take the content of `Xxx_LIBRARIES` I think you can remove the `LOCATION` parameter from `ASSERT_LIBRARY_FUNCTION`. The libraries will come as full paths. See

   - [CMake Developer - Find Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules)

     > Xxx_LIBRARIES: The libraries to link against to use Xxx. These should include full paths. This should not be a cache entry.
   - [CMake Policy CMP0060](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/policy/CMP0060.html)
4. The last one is a very small one: to keep in mind the I possibly handle a list of libraries, I would rename local variable `LIBRARY` to `LIBRARIES`

#### Side Note

Just as a side note [FindBZip2.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBZip2.cmake) has just recently switched to the use of [CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CheckSymbolExists.cmake):

```
cmake_push_check_state()
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET ${BZip2_FIND_QUIETLY})
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS("${BZIP2_LIBRARIES}" BZ2_bzCompressInit "" BZIP2_NEED_PREFIX)
cmake_pop_check_state()
```

With the following comment for the [commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/23876eda9f1d4b5725407aef7d218fc3ce4113cb):

> Run our check for the '_' prefix using a bzip2 API function as declared
>   with a prototype in the real header file.  This is needed in case the
>   function is provided in a DLL import library where the symbol name may
>   not match without proper markup from the header.

#### Footnote

Ever since I have read the following comment in the [`CMP0060` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/policy/CMP0060.html)

> In fact, many [Find Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) are learning to provide [Imported Targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) instead of just the traditional Foo_LIBRARIES variable listing library files.

the thought of "this being something all find modules should have" never left my mind. So here are my five cents for `FindReadline.cmake`:

```
find_path(Readline_INCLUDE_DIR readline/readline.h)
find_library(Readline_LIBRARIES NAMES readline Readline)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs) # handles QUIET, REQUIRED; sets Readline_FOUND
find_package_handle_standard_args(Readline DEFAULT_MSG Readline_LIBRARIES Readline_INCLUDE_DIR)

if(Readline_FOUND AND NOT TARGET Readline::Readline)
    add_library(Readline::Readline UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(
        Readline::Readline 
        PROPERTIES
            IMPORTED_LOCATION "${Readline_LIBRARY}"
            INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${Readline_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    )
endif()

include(AssertLibraryFunction)
assert_library_function(Readline rl_initialize "")
assert_library_function(Readline add_history "")

mark_as_advanced(Readline_INCLUDE_DIR Readline_LIBRARIES)
```